# In IOS, how do you make a share sheet that shares a specific location, like in Maps?

Tags: ios, location, share

in IOS, how do you make a share sheet that shares a specific location, like in Maps? I already tried using a maps.apple.com url with a UIActivityViewController.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to share my current location to UIActivityViewController?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20064781/how-to-share-my-current-location-to-uiactivityviewcontroller)