# How to activate automatic location when posting to Facebook with UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, uiactivityviewcontroller

I would like to share information on facebook via UIActivityViewController. So far no problem, but I would like to understand how to activate automatic location when I get the view of sharing (Location - None). I wish it was active with the current position

[image]

and I would also add "is located at - NAME OF LOCAL". 
You know how to help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20064781/how-to-share-my-current-location-to-uiactivityviewcontroller ?

Comment: I had already seen that discussion, but not exactly what I need, I wanted to know if you can activate the "button" Location of code or if it has to be activated to force user