# UIActivityViewController and CLLocation

Tags: ios, mapkit, core-location, uiactivityviewcontroller

Is it possible to use a UIActivityViewController to share a location?

If it's possible then what type of location object do I need to send?

You can send a location via iMessage so I would assume that it's possible to do this somehow.

Comment: Did you try passing a `CLLocation` object to the `initWithActivityItems:applicationActivities:` method? I would try and see what happens before posting a question.

Comment: Also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20064781/how-to-share-my-current-location-to-uiactivityviewcontroller

Comment: I believe you can do this by creating and sharing a .vcf card with `ABPerson`

Comment: I did try sending a CLLocation but it just shows up without any options. There are so many options it's difficult to know which to use. MKMapItem, CLLocation2D, CLLocation, MKPlacemark etc etc.

Comment: Did you it? @MarkBridges