# select other app installed on your iphone to share location objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-maps, share

I want to share my map location to other apps using location, how can i do that for ios.

I want to do something like this when i click share button.

[image]

Then pass my longitute and latitude when opening the selected app, and it will show me my current location to the location I specified.

Comment: This this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20064781/how-to-share-my-current-location-to-uiactivityviewcontroller). Answer is mentioned. If it doesnt help then let me knw,

Comment: none of it actually answers my question

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use UIActivityViewController like

```
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = 
[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:items applicationActivities:nil]; 
NSArray *excludedActivities = @[UIActivityTypePostToFacebook, 
                                UIActivityTypePostToTwitter,
                                UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, 
                                UIActivityTypeMessage, 
                                UIActivityTypeMail, 
                                UIActivityTypePrint,
                                UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, 
                                UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, 
                                UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll, 
                                UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
                                UIActivityTypePostToFlickr, 
                                UIActivityTypePostToVimeo, 
                                UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo]; 
activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = excludedActivities; 
[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Items is what you want to share, and excludedActivityTypes is the sharing types.